# Is the purpose of std::scoped_lock only to handle multiple mutexes, compared to std::lock_guard?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, c++17

When reading the documentation about [`std::scoped_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock) and [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock), it seams that the only difference is that `scoped_lock` can handle multiple lock guard and can avoid deadlock when unlocking.

Is this the only difference? If I have only one `mutex`, should I therefore keep using use `lock_guard`?

Comment: Nitpick:  The deadlocking is avoided when _locking_.  No unlocking can _never_ create deadlock because unlocking never blocks.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know the only important difference is that the `scoped_lock` has a variadic constructor taking more than one `mutex` as you mentioned. In addition you can implement a single-argument version of `scoped_lock` with template specialization.

So the `lock_guard` is kinda "deprecated" non-formally.

I think `lock_guard` still exists because of **compatibility**.